# Is Auto Uploading Your Browsing History To Mysql DB Possible?

Tags: javascript, php, browser-history

Php Geniuses,

Q1. Is there a way I can auto upload my internet browsing history onto my website's mysql db so I don't have to do it manually one by one ?
Can php do the job or do I have to look into Javascript ?
If php can do it then what php functions would do the job ? Else, which Javascript function ?

Q2. Is there a way I can auto upload my bookmarks onto my website's mysql db so I don't have to do it manually one by one ?
Can php do the job or do I have to look into Javascript ?
If php can do it then what php functions would do the job ? Else, which Javascript function ?

Few yrs back, before del.icio.us was bought by another company, you could auto upload all your bookmarks to your del.icio.us account so that you can later access all your bookmarks on the web from any computer and you did not need to be standing in-front of your home computer to access your bookmarks that you saved on your home computer. I want to build something like that but I don't want the extraction & uploading limited to bookmarks only. Want to extract & upload both bookmarks & browsing history where one script could be for uploading browsing history and the other script for uploading bookmarks.

MySql database
DB Name: links

Tbl Name: bookmarks
Columns: id,date_&_time,urls

Tbl Name: browsing_history
Columns: id,date_&_time,urls

I am thinking of providing a link on my page that when clicked it extracts all your browsing history and uploads it to my db.
I am thinking of providing a link on my page that when clicked it extracts all your bookmarks and uploads it to my db (like del.icio.us used to do in the past before it was sold).

You are aware that, you can access you browsing history by clicking CTRL H. The urls you see in the browsing history list, these must be auto uploaded.

And, you are aware that, you can access you bookmarks by clicking CTRL B. The urls you see in the bookmarks list, these must be auto uploaded.

Comment: There's no programmatic way to access a user's entire browsing history from a webpage. That'd be a huge security issue. Users would need to export their browsing history to a file and then upload the file.

Comment: @JohnEllmore _"There's no programmatic way to access a user's entire browsing history from a webpage."_ Yes, there is. Every request a made from a `window` can be observed programmatically.

Comment: @guest271314 yes, it's all recorded, and yes, you can observe requests, but there's no way to retrieve the _browser's internal browsing history from a webpage using JS APIs_ like Php Learner's asking.

Comment: @JohnEllmore The totality of requests is the browsing history. The entire request history can be retrieved as a `.har` file at DevTools or Developer Tools. All requests from the `window` can be observed using `PerformanceObserver`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can create a browser extension which logs each request made from the browser. You can then post that data, for example as a `.har` file, to a server.

Without using an extension you can use `PerformanceObserver` to observer all requests made from the `document`, send each entry as `JSON` to server.

Answer (score -1):

The server has no access to the browser history, so server-side code can't access it.

JavaScript embedded in a webpage has no access to the browser history.

Browser extensions might (but the specifics would depend on which browser you were using). Stand-along software running on the computer hosting the browser might (and again, the specifics would depend on which browser you were using).

Either of those two options could upload the results to your server where you could process it with whatever language you liked (including PHP and JavaScript (e.g. with Node.js)).